# How to read a string into a line (unknown length)

Tags: bash, unix, input

How do I get a line of unknown length from a user as a string into variable in bash?

I want to call function with $1 $2 $3 and so on, but every time the length, or in other words the amount of parameters can change.

I tried to do "read -e" and some other options, I would glad to get some help for that simple quest.

```
function find_sus {

while read -a domain; do #here I try to write the parameters into an array
p=0
while((p<$2)); do #Here just fo a check, I try to print all the array's elements
echo ${domain[p]};
let p++;
done 

read -e domains #Here I want to read into domains a string 
find_sus $domains $# #here I want to give the string and the amount of parameters to the function
```

Generally, I have function and I want to give here an unknown amount of parameters, one in a time, and then in the function for each parameter do operations with already written scripts.

Ok, for more clearance, My function is find_suspect.
I'll tell you my problem. All I know is how to give the function finite and not big number of parameters, like find_suspect $1 $2 $3 and so on.

Can anybody give me an example of how to give a function n parameters, without writing them all as $1 ... $n. 
I tried to do it with a loop 
    while ((i

but of course it isn't the right way to do it.

Comment: Did `read` not work for some reason? What *exactly* did you try? How *exactly* did it not work? What *exactly* are you trying to end up with (show us an approximation of the code you want)?

Comment: Strings of unknown length can be read into a shell script _easily_.  You need to show us, as EtanReisner requests, exactly what problem you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the unknown nr of parameters with shift:

```
clear

function findsus {
   while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
      echo Param $1
      shift
   done
}

findsus one two three
findsus 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
findsus "Argument in quotes"
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to supply as single string as the argument to `readsus` and then have `readsus` break it into individual words and print one word per line.  If that is the case, define `readsus` like this:

```
$ findsus() { for d in $*; do echo "$d"; done; }
```

`$*` provides all the arguments.  Since it is unquoted, the shell breaks it into words.

For example:

```
$ findsus "abc.com def.com a.net"
abc.com
def.com
a.net
```

#### Improvement: Avoiding pathname expansion

In the above, the shell performs both word splitting (which we want) and pathname expansion (which we may not).  With an extra step, we can split the input string up into an array *without* the shell performing pathname expansion:

```
$ findsus() { read -r -a domains <<<"$*"; for d in "${domains[@]}"; do echo "$d"; done; }
$ findsus "abc.com * def.com"
abc.com
*
def.com
```

Comment: What if there are glob characters?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf OK.  I added a method to avoid pathname expansion.